# Why is my class not accepting arguments in python?

Tags: python, oop

Context: The full code isn't below as to make it easier to read. Therefore some of the code may not make sense as it isn't used. Also the big picture is that I am attempting to make a object orientated text based adventure in python.

The problem I have is that I'm trying to have a gate object then create instances of it in order to use in the setup function of my level object. However it is throwing up an error that the gate object does not accept arguments and I was wondering how I would go about fixing this.

The type of code throwing this error looks like this: gate1 = gate("north", deep_forest_area)

```
#EXCRIPT OF TEXT BASED ADVENTURE OOP PYTHON PROGRAM

#defines level class
class level():
    def __innit__(self):
        self.name = ("")

    #level setup function
    def setup(self, name, directions, description):
        self.name = name
        self.directions = directions
        self.description = description
        

    def enter(self):
        print(self.description)
        if len(self.directions) >= 1:
            print("there is a gate to ", end=" ")
            for d in self.directions:
                d.print_gate()

#defines gate class
class gate:

    def __innit__(self, direction, gate_to):
        self.gate_to = gate_to
        self.direction = direction

    def is_gate(self, text):
        return self.direction in text

    def print_gate(self):
        print("the %s," % self.direction, end= " ")

#initialises levels
start_area = level()
deep_forest_area = level()


#defines gates and levels
gate1 = gate("north", deep_forest_area)
start_area.setup("forest", [gate1], "You are in a dusk lit forest surrounded by trees. The only direction is deeper into the forest")

gate1 = gate("south", start_area)
deep_forest_area.setup("deep forest", [gate1], "You are in a seemingly endless tunnel of dark oak trees")
```

I tried analysing the code logically in terms of class logic and instances etc, however I couldn't see anything wrong and I feel as if I'm missing out on a piece of information or something.

I also tried copying the template code I was working off more heavily but the error still didn't budge, which is weird because I was border line copying at one point out of frustration. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor should be called `__init__` and not `__innit__`. Since your classes don't have a constructor, python provides a default, no arg constructor and you cannot pass any arguments to it, hence the error.

Comment: Punching myself right now. I assumed there would be an error for misspelling but I see how python interprets the code now. Thanks for the answer.